# c++ std::istringstream weird std::hex behaviour

Tags: c++, hex, istringstream

**EDIT:**

I managed to get the same problem on a smaller scale:

```
std::istringstream hex;
std::string str = "0x7ffa428ab946";
std::cout << "str " << str << std::endl;
hex.str(str);
long caller;
hex >> std::hex >> caller;
std::cout << "caller " << caller << std::endl;
str = "0x7ff9ec0010f0";
std::cout << "str " << str << std::endl;
hex.str(str);
long address;
hex >> std::hex >> address;
std::cout << "address " << address << std::endl;
```

and get this:

```
str 0x7ffa428ab946
caller 140712834939206
str 0x7ff9ec0010f0
address 0
```

why is that?

Comment: _"Does this have to do with quantum mechanics ?"_ How on earth is this related to quantum mechanics ?

Comment: @P0W sorry it was a small joke, since I am clueless to what might cause this..

Comment: It sounds like this question can be shortened down to one or two lines of code

Comment: @keyser I did it, more then 2 lines though.

Comment: `hex.str(str)` doesn't clear `eofbit`, so the second extraction will just fail. Add a `hex.clear();` after that call.

Comment: @Vladp: what is `sizeof(long)` on your machine ?

Comment: @T.C. you are right, after the first extraction the hex.eof() is true, and every next extraction fails. please post an answer I can accept.

Comment: If you wanted the `caller` line to show a matching value, you'd also need to use `std::cout << "caller " << std::hex << caller`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hex >> std::hex >> caller;
```

will set `eofbit` on `hex`, but the subsequent

```
hex.str(str);
```

doesn't clear it. Thus, later attempts to extract from `hex` will simply fail.

Call `hex.clear()` after the `hex.str(str);` call to clear the flags.